# How to prioritize bandwidth in linux

Tags: linux, networking, debian, bandwidth, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian acting as a 24x7 downloading server. I am now trying to utilize it with SiriProxy but it fails as it needs to upload/download data from Apple servers which fails because we have downloads running in background not leaving enough datapipe for Siriproxy to work as expected. I studied `trickle` but it is not what I need as it permanently limits the bandwidth for an application, I need something which will work like `nice` command prioritizing network for Siriproxy only when needed.

Comment: Category kernel network management. What is QoS?

Comment: the `tc` [command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-traffic-shaping-using-tc-to-control-http-traffic/) seems whats needed the only problem is it seems way to out of my league :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick for me - http://www.funtoo.org/Traffic_Control, just edited rules in the script provided as per my needs and everything works as expected.